# How can I install Draftsight?

Tags: software-installation

There is an error which shows: "Dependency is not satisfiable: libxcb-render-util0 (>= 0.3.6-1)"

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: do you have the universe repository enabled ?

Answer (score 2):

There is one solution if you use Ubuntu 11.10...

1. Install this package http://launchpadlibrarian.net/40396571/libxcb-render-util0_0.3.6-1build1_i386.deb
2. Download draftsight package http://www.draftsight.com/download-linux-ubuntu
3. Install it....
4. Done

Answer (score 1):

open your synaptic manager and look for that package and install it from there and try again with installing what you wanna do .

Comment: Actually, you won't find the package in Synaptic, else the error wouldn't have appeared.

Comment: Hi , I am talking about libxcb-render-util0 package . If its not available in synaptic then http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxcb-render-util0  . Get that package from this link and install it .  All the Best.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of Ubuntu you're using.

- If you're using some version other than 11.10, make sure that you have the universe enabled in Software Sources.
- If you're using 11.10, you're out of luck. For whatever reason, Oneiric (11.10) doesn't include this package. You can try to install [the version in Precise (12.04)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libs/libxcb-render-util0), but there's no guarantee that it'll work, and it's possible that it could break your system.